# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to access a managed object property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I'm having some trouble dealing with Core Data+concurrency/nested MOCs (not sure which one I'm having problems with =P).

I have a method where I pass in a managed object ID (I checked that it's permanent) and that method has a child managed object context that is confined to a certain queue. I can retrieve the object from the child managed object context via `[managedObjectContext objectWithID:moID]` but when I try to access any of its properties (the managed object is still a fault), I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with the stack trace showing `_svfk_1` and `objc_msgSend`.

I know it's kind of difficult to figure out what the problem is without sample code, but I was hoping someone could shed some light on the possible causes. Thanks. =)

**EDIT:** I tried using `existingObjectWithID:error:` instead of `objectWithID:` as Tom Harrington suggested and now it works sometimes but doesn't work other times. I also experienced an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash on `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`. I suspect this could be a synchronization issue. If I edit something in one context and save while something else is edited in my child context, would that cause an issue?

**EDIT 2:** I figured out why existingObjectWithID:error: was working sometimes but not always. The managed object ID was indeed a temporary ID (shouldn't `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` convert it to a permanent ID?), so I had to call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` before passing the ID. But I'm still getting crashes sometimes in the child context's `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`. What could be the possible causes of this? Thanks.

**EDIT 3:** Here's what my MOC hierarchy looks like.

```
   Persistent Store Coordinator
                |
      Persistent Store MOC
         /            \
Main Queue MOC   Child MOC (confinement)
```

I'm invoking a method from the main queue that uses the Child MOC (in another queue) to insert and update some managed objects and at the same time, I'm inserting and updating managed objects in the Persistent Store MOC. Managed objects can also be updated, deleted, and inserted in the Main Queue MOC at the same time. I merge any changes from the Persistent Store Coordinator to both the Main Queue MOC and the Child MOC.

Some more questions: Does saving an MOC automatically merge things? If there is a pending merge request for an MOC and you save before that merge request is processed, can that cause issues?

**EDIT 4:** Here's how I initialize the Child MOC.

```
dispatch_sync(_searchQueue, ^{
    _searchManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];

    [_searchManagedObjectContext setParentContext:_persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    [_searchManagedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
});
```

Btw, I notice that the merge only crashes (with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) when the notification contains deleted objects.

Comment: Oh: "The data in the persistent store represented by objectID is assumed to exist—if it does not, the returned object throws an exception when you access any property (that is, when the fault is fired)." Let me check up on this.

Comment: Nope, I added a breakpoint in `prepareForDeletion` in my managed object subclass, but it was never fired. So the managed object has not been deleted when I call this method.

Comment: do you use performBlock to talk to the child MOC (I assume that's not on main queue)?

Comment: The child MOC is confined to a serial queue and I do all operations with the child MOC on that queue.

Comment: try to turn on NSZombie and see if you're accessing deallocated instance, just in case :)

Comment: Done. No `NSZombie` warnings and it still crashes. =(

Comment: Try replacing `objectWithID:` with `existingObjectWithID:error:` and see what happens.

Comment: WOAH…it works!! What happened?!

Comment: Shouldn't they do the same thing if the managed object exists in the persistent store?

Comment: The only difference should be that the managed object is faulted in if you use `existingObjectWithID:error:`, right!?

Comment: I think this issue is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453100/unexplained-behavioural-difference-between-objectwithid-versus-existingobjectwi), no?

Comment: Yes, they should be the same if the object exists in the data store. If results are different with that change, the objects probably don't exist. If you get different results at different times, you have a race condition, probably due to threading/queueing errors. Beyond that it's hard to be sure without seeing some code.

Comment: How do you allocate and initialize your `Child MOC (confinement)`? Please, post code snippet here?

Comment: Hm, I am not sure that it will help, but old (confinement) context initialization style is: `_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType]; [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];`

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski My understanding is that if you set a parent context, then it will act like a persistent store coordinator. And the confinement concurrency type just means that I will manage threading myself.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Last question. Do you use background context somewhere else except background thread? I've noticed that you assign it to ivar _searchManagedObjectContext. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski _searchManagedObjectContext is my Child MOC and I only use it on the _searchQueue serial dispatch queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. Before every save, I do `[moc obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[[moc insertedObjects] allObjects] error:&error]`. Now I don't get any more crashes.

I'm still a bit murky on what exactly was going on, but here's my understanding. When you save newly inserted objects, they are only assigned a permanent ID when the MOC connected to the persistent store coordinator saves. Now, either `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` propagated the permanent IDs back down (as I had expected) and some other operation just happened to occur just before the merge or there's an Apple bug somewhere. In any case, obtaining the permanent IDs beforehand solved the issue.

TL;DR Core Data+concurrency is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're still working too hard. For your child MOC, since it's in a serial queue, use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and set its parent to your main MOC.

`NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is for legacy configurations.